# Center Link using sliding door CSS

Tags: css, center, sliding-doors

I'm trying to center the entire link and i'm struggling for a solution. I'm using a simple sliding door style for my link and I'd like it to be center.

Here's a demo you can interact with: http://jsbin.com/ibidu3

```
<style>
  a.btn_blue {
  background:url("http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/2600/btnblueleft.gif") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    float:left;
  text-decoration:none;
  margin-right:4px;
  padding-left:5px;
  color:#fff;
  }

a.btn_blue span{
    background:url("http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/1531/btnblueright.gif") no-repeat scroll right top transparent;
    float:left;
  padding:6px 10px 10px 4px;
  }
  </style>

<a href="#" class="btn_blue"><span>Learn More: <strong>Benefits</strong></span></a>
```

Comment: What are you referring to by "sliding door"?

Comment: @Ryan, he's referring the CSS approach of 'infintely-expandable' backgrounds (so text can be zoomed without breaking the site's design), there's an article at [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/) that explains it.

Comment: @Evan, is there a reason you chose to go with sliding doors, instead of using `background-colour`, css-gradients, `border-radius`..? Your `btn_blue` seems incredibly fragile, and persistent.

Comment: David - i chose to use the sliding door effect so the button can expand that way using the same graphic concept would be simple if we need smaller or larger buttons. i thought by adding a ".btn_blue" class and display:block would help me, but i'm hurting for a solution. what's your thoughts?

Comment: @Evan (note the '@', if it's there I'll be notified of new replies) looking at your jsbin demo, I'd suggest (depending on how many buttons you're going to put together) using `li` elements or maybe a couple of `spans` styled appropriately. I'll see if I can come up with something useful for you to look at. Oh, and what browsers does it need to work in?

Comment: @David Thanks for the @ trick. I didn't know that... As for the button link, it exists each inside 3 columns of content, while the content is left justified, the button needs to be centered. As a dirty trick, I just padded the button 55 pixels to the left and that "faked" centered it, but i didn't know if there's a proper way of doing it?

Comment: @Evan - u want it with respect to what? do u want the text centered with respect to the button?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about text not being centered within the anchor tag then that is due to ppadding  in `a.btn_blue span` being different on the left and right side. `padding:6px 10px 10px 6px;`

Comment: I'm talking about the link being centered of a div. ultimately, the link will exist within a "div class".

Comment: @your test link does not have it could ypu update it or atleast post the complete html